# Problems with icon_drawable in navegation Drawable

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am trying to show Icon_drawble in a ActionBar, but when R.drawable.ic_drawer is in the first position show return arrow in actionbar.

like this:

[image]

```
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,
                mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,
                R.string.drawer_open, 
                R.string.drawer_close

                ) {
```

I need to show something like this, but the code above It doesnt work.

[image]

If  I change R.drawable.ic_drawer to another position,it give me the follow logcat error.

```
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,
                mDrawerLayout,

                R.string.drawer_open,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,//another position
                R.string.drawer_close 

                )
```

Logcat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.navegatiodrawer/com.example.navegatiodrawer.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File Open navigation drawer from drawable resource ID
```

Comment: Do you have an icon named "ic_drawer.png" in your drawable resource folders?

Comment: yes, I have the ic_drawer in my drawable source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in recent versions of the AppCompat library.

Part of the confusion is likely due to the fact that Android Studio's new project wizard generates bad code when you create a new navigation drawer activity- it uses the [v4 support library `ActionBarDrawerToggle`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html), which is deprecated. Instead, it should use the [v7 support library `ActionBarDrawerToggle`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html).

You have two options:

- The best option is to switch to the v7 `ActionBarDrawerToggle`. To do this, change your imports to use `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle` instead of `android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle`. The only other change you should need to make is removing your `ic_drawer` parameter altogether- the newer version of the toggle generates the hamburger you are looking for automatically.
- If you insist on using the v4 toggle or a custom icon, you can revert to an older version of the support library. Using the default generated project when creating a new navigation drawer activity, I was able to sidestep this bug by reverting to `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0` in my build.gradle.

There is already [a bug in the issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=161456&q=navigation%20drawer&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars) for updating the wizard-generated code. I wouldn't expect the v4 toggle to get fixed since it is deprecated.

Comment: I switch to the  v7 ActionBarDrawerToggl and it works.